# Why is std::string s = "123" considered copy-initialisation when no copy is involved?

Tags: c++

Why is this way of initialisating a std::string:
`std::string s = "123";`
considered a copy initialisation, when no copy whatsoever actually occurs?

In the above case, there is no ambiguity that the compiler will see that there is a `std::string` constructor that takes a `char const *`, and consequently what happens here is construction of a `std::string` object via implicit conversion of `char const *` to `std::string`. This is such a clear-cut scenario. It's simply calling a `std::string(const char *)` constructor **once**, plain and simple. So simple there is even nothing to talk about regarding optimisations such as copy elision and move.

Now, the problem is, I never had any confusion about object initialisation via implicit conversion (i.e. Class a = expression) until I started coming across literature declaring that initialisation by = is "copy initialisation". Even the main man, Bjarne Stroustrup himself, refers to this form of initialisation as "copy initialisation".

At this point, I feel that I may be misunderstanding something.

So, why is initialisation by = considered copy-initialisation when clearly this is not the case if implicit conversion is allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) is simply used for an initializing syntax of the form:

```
T object = other;
```

where one of the effects of this initialization is:

> If T is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the type of other is not T or derived from T, or if T is non-class type, but the type of other is a class type, user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the type of other to T (or to a type derived from T if T is a class type and a conversion function is available) are examined and the best one is selected through overload resolution.

So for the expression:

```
std::string s = "123";
```

the implicit [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes a `const char *` is used to construct the `std::string`.

So even though it has the term *copy* in it, copy-initialization does not mean there is an actual *copy* involved, it's only called that because the syntax makes it *appear* like a copy is happening.

Comment: Thanks - I think you found the heart of the matter here: **" ... user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the type of other to T ... are examined and the best one is selected ..."** So, that clearly states that implicit conversion is indeed part of the definition of "copy initialisation". I need to read the specs with an eye of a lawyer! :)

Comment: Only if you want to know the exact rules :) Most c++ programmers don't need to know most of the details to write good code. Also note that I'm quoting cppreference, not the standard, which is the official document.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is called copy initialization is because before C++11, that is what literally had to be done, per the rules of the language.  When you have

```
T t = u;
```

if `u` is a `T`, then you call the copy constructor.  So calling it copy initialization for that case makes sense

if `u` is not a `T` then [dcl.init]/15 bullet 7 came into play ([from the C++03 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf)) and that has

> Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). If the conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed. The function selected is called with the initializer expression as its argument; **if the function is a constructor, the call initializes a temporary of the cv-unqualified version of the destination type. The temporary is an rvalue. The result of the call (which is the temporary for the constructor case) is then used to direct-initialize, according to the rules above, the object that is the destination of the copy-initialization.** In certain cases, an implementation is permitted to eliminate the copying inherent in this direct-initialization by constructing the intermediate result directly into the object being initialized; see 12.2, 12.8.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

which states that a temporary is created, and that temporary is used to initialize them object.  Yes, it says this can be avoided in certain cases, but those section only allow the optimization, it is not mandated to happen.

So, again we are making a copy, so copy initialization makes sense.

With C++17 this is no longer the case and your guaranteed that no copy will exist, but were stuck with the name at this point.

Comment: Optimisations aside, and regardless of C++ version, if u is not a T, copy construction will not take place if there is a constructor that implicitly converts u to T. The pertinent section in the specs above is: **... user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source type to the destination type or ... are enumerated ... and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ...**, as pointed out by the answer by @cigien

Comment: @moog cigien is using the newest standard that makes how you think it happens true.  In the old days, it wasn't true, or at least it wasn't guaranteed that a copy would not happen.  This is what made C++11, and then C++17 so great.  C++11 introduced move semantics so if a copy was made, a move could happen instead and C++17 finally said you no what, no sane compiler wont optimize this away, so lets just guarantee the behavior.